# MySQL drop tables that are not

Tags: mysql

I cant seem to be finding the answer anywhere for the question above.

for deleting specific tables I use:

```
DROP TABLE table1, table2;
```

What I want to do is drop every table excluding table1 and table2. however I don't know the query and googling didn't help.

For example pseudo code:

```
DROP TABLE IF IT IS NOT table1, table2;
```

Seems like the question is not as clear as I thought, sorry I don't know how else to explain it,
here is code example, hope it clears up the question;

```
foreach (table tb in database)
{
   if (table.Name != "table1" && table.Name != "table2")
   {
       database.DropTable(tb);
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why dont you delete them one by one? is there a reason you are checking for them?

Comment: The thing is I have a list of table names which are original tables, and there are some that have been created later which are unnecessary, I cant go through and delete all the extra ones, I just want to keep the originals.

Comment: the "like" clause is used for filtering data.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a new database with only the tables you  want, and then delete the old database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT('drop table ',table_name,'; ')
FROM information_schema.tables
where table_name like 'table1%'
   and table_schema = 'myDatabase';
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996617/mysql-deleting-some-specific-tables-from-big-database)

Comment: wouldn't that basically delete table1 and table2?

Comment: can you update your op in the case I have understood this wrong.

Comment: Yup, that pretty much deletes table1 and table2, sorry, I don't know how to be clearer, I basially want to delete every other table except table1 and table 2

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by that secure in what way? @Strawberry